# Bank Account TransferTo Method

Tags: java, methods, transfer

Ok I am having problems creating a transfer to method to transfer "money" from one account to the next. After the transfer the amounts of each account would be printed out. I created the code but when I run it the amount transferred is set to the bank account amount. It should just deduct from one account and add to the next account. What am I doing wrong?

**This is my class with contructors and methods:**

```
public class Account {
// Instance variables
private double balance;

// Constructors
public Account(double initialBalance) {
    balance = initialBalance;
}

public Account(int account, double balance) {
    this.balance = balance;
}

public Account() {
    balance = 0.0;
}

// Instance methods

public void setBalance() {
    balance = Math.random() * 1000;
    balance = Math.round((balance * 100.0)+.5) / 100.0;
}

public void deposit(double amount) {
    balance = balance + amount;
}

public void withdraw(double amount) {
    balance = balance - amount;
}

public double getBalance() {
    balance = Math.round((balance * 100.0)+.5) / 100.0;
    return balance;
}

public void close() {
    balance = 0.0;
}

public void transferTo(Account bank, double x) {
    if (x <= balance) {
        withdraw(x);
        bank.deposit(x);
        System.out.println("\nTransfer succesful. Tansfered: $" + bank.getBalance());
    } else if (x > balance) {
        System.out.println("\nTransfer failed, not enough balance!");
    }
}
}
```

**This is my class with the main method**

```
public class MyBank {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Account[] bank = { new Account(), new Account(), new Account(),
            new Account() };

    bank[0].setBalance();
    bank[1].setBalance();
    bank[2].setBalance();
    bank[3].setBalance();

    System.out.println("Accounts 1 balance is: $" + bank[0].getBalance());
    System.out.println("Accounts 2 balance is: $" + bank[1].getBalance());
    System.out.println("Accounts 3 balance is: $" + bank[2].getBalance());
    System.out.println("Accounts 4 balance is: $" + bank[3].getBalance());

    double x = Math.random()*100;
    bank[0].transferTo(bank[1], x);
    System.out.println("Remaining balance of Account 1: $" + bank[0].getBalance());
    System.out.println("Remaining balance of Account 2: $" + bank[1].getBalance());

    double y = (Math.random()*300);
    bank[2].transferTo(bank[3], y);
    System.out.println("Remaining balance of Account 3: $" + bank[2].getBalance());
    System.out.println("Remaining balance of Account 4: $" + bank[3].getBalance());
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One issue you did have, is that you were accidentally printing the BALANCE rather than the amount actually transferred, in your `transferTo()` method. I fixed this. On another note, if you're going to be printing these numbers out, [look into printf()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/numberformat.html) to make them appear as actual dollar amounts. I did it to one of the lines to show you an example.

PS - Try NOT using Math.random() for stuff when you're trying to debug.

```
public void transferTo(Account bank, double x) {
    if (x <= this.balance) {
        withdraw(x);
        bank.deposit(x);
        System.out.println("\nTransfer succesful. Tansfered: $" + x);
    } else { //does not need to be else if, because if not <=, it MUST be >.
        System.out.println("\nTransfer failed, not enough balance!");
    }
}
```

I can verify that the method works perfectly fine, after these edits, on my machine. This is what I used to test:

```
public class MyBank {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Account[] bank = { new Account(), new Account(), new Account(),
            new Account() };

    bank[0].setBalance();
    bank[1].setBalance();
    bank[2].setBalance();
    bank[3].setBalance();

    double x = 100.00;
    System.out.printf("Transferring $%.2f from Acc 1 to Acc 2.\n", x); //printf example
    System.out.println("Acc 1 previous balance: " + bank[0].getBalance());
    System.out.println("Acc 2 previous balance: " + bank[1].getBalance());
    bank[0].transferTo(bank[1], x);
    
    
    System.out.println("Acc 1 new balance: " + bank[0].getBalance());
    System.out.println("Acc 2 new balance: " + bank[1].getBalance());
        
        
}
}
```

And lastly, my output:

> Transferring $100.00 from Acc 1 to Acc 2.
>
> Acc 1 previous balance: 106.76
>
> Acc 2 previous balance: 266.18
>
> Transfer succesful. Transfered: $100.0
>
> Acc 1 new balance: 6.77
>
> Acc 2 new balance: 366.19

Comment: -1 This is not a mistake, and does not stop the code from working. It is purely a preference issue.

Comment: @immibis edited, thanks for the acknowledgement. Realized I was incorrect.

Comment: `x()` should still be `x`.

Comment: Thank you! This worked perfectly. I knew it had to do with the balance I just couldnt figure it out. Thank you again!

Comment: @Victor no problem! Please consider upvoting and/or marking my answer correct if you're satisfied with it.

Answer (score 0):

```
System.out.println("\nTransfer succesful. Tansfered: $" + bank.getBalance());
```

This prints the other account's new balance, because *that's what you told it to do*.

If you want to print the amount transferred:

```
System.out.println("\nTransfer succesful. Tansfered: $" + x);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
// Bank account class
class BankAccount {
  constructor(fname, lname, account_number) {
    const minBalance = 10000;
    this.name = `${fname} ${lname}`;
    this.balance = minBalance;
    this.account_number = account_number;
  }

  details() {
    console.log(
      `Cleint name: ${this.name} \n Balance: ${this.balance} \n Account number: ${this.account_number}`
    );
  }

  isPositive(amount) {
    return amount > 0 ? true : false;
  }

  isVlaidAmount(amount) {
    return isNaN(amount) || !this.isPositive(amount) ? false : true;
  }

  deposit(amount) {
    if (this.isVlaidAmount(amount)) {
      this.balance += amount;
    } else {
      console.log("Sorry, this transcation cannot be completed!");
    }
  }

  withdraw(amount) {
    if (this.isVlaidAmount(amount)) {
      this.balance -= amount;
    } else {
      console.log("Sorry, you have insufficient funds.");
    }
  }

  transfer(amount, reciever) {
    if (this.isVlaidAmount(amount)) {
      this.withdraw(amount);
      reciever.deposit(amount);
    }
  }
}

// create objects
let acc1 = new BankAccount("George", "Omara", 422);
let acc2 = new BankAccount("Haward", "Walowets", 662);
```

Comment: Please explain the problem and how your answer solves it.

Comment: Sorry for not documenting the code, kinda my first post. i'll do better next time. the code was to showing a way of making the "transferTo()" method work. however in my code i named the method "transfer"

Comment: No problem. You can edit your current answer with description.